# Change variable value when signal is trapped in Fortran

Tags: fortran, signals

While developing the program on Fortran, that employs some iteration procedure, I faced the necessity to stop iterations manually (to exit from the iteration loop without program termination).

I decided to do it sending a signal to the process. I have chosen SIGALRM. I have checked that it can be trapped without any unexpected consequences.

When received signal, the flag value is changed. This flag is checked inside the iteration loop and exit if flag is true. The sample of such code is given below.

```
!file mymod.f90
module mymod
use ifport
integer*4            :: err
integer*4            :: SIGNSET
integer*4, parameter :: mySignal=14
logical*1            :: toStopIteration

contains
!   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ !
    integer*4 function setTrap() result(ret)
    implicit none

    call PXFSTRUCTCREATE('sigset',SIGNSET,err)
    call PXFSIGADDSET(SIGNSET,mySignal,err) !add my signal to the set.

    ret=0; return
    end function setTrap
!   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ !
    integer*4 function onTrap(sig_num) result(rcode)
    implicit none
    integer*4 :: sig_num,err

    rcode=0
    select case (sig_num)
        case(mySignal)
            write (*,*) 'Signal occurred. Stop iteration called'
            write (*,*) 'flag: ',toStopIteration
            toStopIteration=.true.
            write (*,*) 'flag: ',toStopIteration
            rcode=1
            return
        case (SIGINT) ; stop
        case (SIGTERM); stop
        case (SIGABRT); stop
    end select

    end function onTrap
!   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ !
end module mymod

!file main.f90
program main
use mymod
implicit none
integer*4 :: i,j,N,Niters,sum1

err=setTrap()
err=signal(mySignal, onTrap, -1)

toStopIteration=.false.

open (1,file='output')
write (*,*) 'PID=',getpid()
write (1,*) 'Outside',toStopIteration

N=5000000; Niters=100000

do i = 1,Niters
    if (toStopIteration) then
        toStopIteration=.false.
        exit
    endif

    sum1=0
    do j = 1,N
        sum1=sum1+j
    enddo
    write (1,*) i,toStopIteration,sum1
enddo

write (*,*) 'Procedure was terminated due to signal received. The last iteration was', i
write (*,*) 'Now I will do other job for you.'

stop
end program main
```

Application was compiled with ifort: `ifort -c -O2 -traceback`.
When I send signal to the process `kill -14 pid`,
I get output to the terminal:

```
 Signal occurred. Stop iteration called
 flag:  F
 flag:  T
```

But iteration loop is still running and as written in the file, variable "toStopIteration" is equal false.

Accidentally, I have found out that when compiled with `-O0 -traceback` parameter, it works fine.
Why does it happen? Does variable "toStopIteration" become local with such optimization level? And what can I do to make it work correctly?

Thanks in advance.
MuKeP.

Comment: For all, who will find this question and need the details. You need to use `logical*1, volatile :: toStopIteration` statement. But as I understood correctly, it is a feature that appeared in the 2003 Fortran standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Lorri answered (unfortunately that succinct, but correct, answer has been deleted by misdirected reviews) - try the volatile attribute on toStopIteration.  This tells the compiler that the variable might be redefined by something else, otherwise from the source visible to the compiler it looks like the value of that variable cannot change in an iteration, and therefore there is no point testing it each iteration.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It has solved my problem. Maybe it is better for me to read the specification more accurately :).